# Windows 2008 R2 with CITRIX - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: object, reference

My application have been implemented on .NET 4.0 . As of now my application was deployed in Windows 2003 Server and published to Citrix Environment for Users in the production. 
We are planning to migrate to Windows Server 2008 R2 in the production.After deploying the application in Citrix environment , we are getting the following error message (object reference not set to an instance of an object), when I click on the dropdown control. After some time my application is getting crash. Is there any security related issue? .Because, once I have the admin rights to that server,I am not getting any issues.

We are using DllImport("User32") in VB.NET for warning balloon. Do we need to provide any extra security setup for this?

Comment: And also we are using the following DLL in my custom .NET Framework
uxtheme.dll
comctl32.dll
user32.dll
tapi32.dll